# Minimum 50 reputation to post comments can be circumvented by posting a trivial answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, reputation

A *minimum* reputation of **50** is required to **post comments** on questions.

This can be circumvented by posting a very short answer (in my case 39 characters or so). Stack Overflow then detects it as a trivial answer and posts it as a comment instead.

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: It is not "stackoverflow" but its users who flag the answer as a non-answer, and then a moderator can change it into a comment. Yes it is intended site behavior, in order to both get rid of bad answers and to migrate what should be a comment into the comment section of the question, but if this is misused, the poster may be eventually answer-banned, which also is intended site behavior, made to prevent more bad or non-answers from being posted by that user.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But in this case it happened instantly, which suggests it's automated behaviour when a short answer is posted, not moderation. A user with less than 50 rep can post a comment, whilst they normally cant.

Comment: Then it is a new feature that I am not aware of. I don't know what algorithm can be used to immediately detect a non-answer, unless there is a bot that searches and finds answers that contain text like, "I know that this shouldn't be posted as an answer...."

Comment: @Ozzy your attempted answer consisted of "possible duplicate <link to SO post>"... The system deems that better/safe enough as a comment... You won't be able to edit that comment though... So it's not an avenue of abuse.

Comment: Same kind of vein as users with <50 rep can still flag as a duplicate and it leaves an auto-comment - the person just can't edit like they could if they had 50 rep.

Comment: @JonClements Yes it is. In that case it isn't a bug. Shall I close this question?

Comment: I'll mark it as status by design for now as no doubt others might also think it's odd. I can't find a post where this is explained right now (if there is one)... So while not a bug - it's still a useful post to have about for others who may wonder the same thing in future.

Comment: FWIW, this is not new, I even got the commentator badge before I got to the 50 rep :P

Comment: @Jon Clements: This is a different issue, see Laurel's answer, which links to my MSE post on the subject. I suspected it was the same issue based on the fact that the asker specifically used the phrase "trivial answer" in the title.

Comment: Very often I'll come across an "I don't have enough rep to post a comment so I'll post this as an answer instead". What I find bewildering is that it seems to be generally found acceptable by other users. If we are going to say a low rep. user cannot be trusted to post a comment, we certainly shouldn't accept that they post the same text in an answer. But could it be the opposite? Maybe the comment limitation is just unnecessary and people accept the workaround because we don't want the rule?

Answer (score 51):

There's a feature that converts answers to comments automatically:

> Trivial answers containing a link to another question in the network are automatically converted to comments on the question, with the message
>
> > Trivial answer converted to comment
>
> <sub>[Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/323179)</sub>

(No answer is actually posted in this process (not even a deleted one) [according to this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107064/323179).)

**However,** it's probably not intentional that users without the 50 rep "Comment Everywhere" privilege can post comments this way. "This can't be what's intended" is, in fact, what [Tim Post (a Stack Overflow employee) said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233962/323179) when this exact thing was reported 4 years ago by a Stack Overflow moderator.

Although there's less potential for abuse for this bug than questions and answers, comment abuse can and has already been done with this bug (as you can tell from the one linked post).

Answer (score 33):

This is definitely by-design. It's triggered by an answer containing a link to another Stack Overflow/Exchange post and *at most* 75 characters of context... In other words, a "link-mostly answer".

And yes, this allows low-rep users to comment... With one caveat: they cannot *edit* those comments. Oh, and all of the caveats in the previous paragraph. Plus some implicit caveats that apply to answers but don't normally apply to comments. So, really, the following list of caveats:

1. Comment must contain a link to another Stack Exchange post.
2. Comment cannot be more than 75 characters long outside of that link.
3. Once converted, the comment cannot be edited (and thus, the link cannot be removed nor the length extended).
4. Because the comment starts as an answer, it's subject to all of the normal validation, quality-control, spam-checks and rate-limits that apply to answers. Which I won't bother enumerating here, but... They are considerably more extensive than anything that exists for comments.

Comment: If one day we could add a spellchecking check, I would be grateful. :D

Comment: Does the 75 characters include the link itself? @Cœur Desktop browsers already have spell check.

Comment: @jpmc26: "2. Comment cannot be more than 75 characters long outside of that link."

Comment: @BoltClock My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: So you are telling that if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334764/5358284) had a link, it would have been automatically converted into a comment? But then again, it is too short to be a comment either :/

Comment: Does posting an answer that is converted to a comment counted against the user in some manner, like an answer ban (is that even a thing?)?  I ask because I'd rather dis-incentivize new users from circumventing the privilege barrier by just clogging up the review queue.

Comment: Is the question bumped in that case?

Comment: @zero298 [Yes, that is a thing.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Nope, @zero298 - an answer is never actually created when this happens. There's a little message shown to the author indicating what happened, but beyond that it is to the system as though they simply commented.

Comment: Since they are detecting "link-mostly" answers, I'd like to see them go away completely.  In many cases, the link does not perfectly answer the original question, and is usually "go read this and figure it out."  That's not really an answer at all, and ironically the reason for many questions is poor documentation.  If the link is to another stack exchange question that is the perfect answer, the question is then a perfect duplicate and can be eliminated.